# How to write an .htaccess that changes "/folder1/folder2/" to "/"

Tags: .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite, ctf

I'm trying to make a ctf challenge involving local file inclusion.

With that in mind, I've recreated a "linux" like folder system with `/etc/`, `/var/`, `/home` etc ... because I use a free web hosting service.

In order to not look suspicious to the users I want to change just graphicly the URL to make it look like the user is at the root directory while he is indeed in an other subdirectory (also the user need to be able to include `../../etc/passwd`). So far this is what I have :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/
```

and this file is located in `/folder1/folder2/`, but it does nothing ...

Can someone help me?

PS : Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/
> ```

By itself, the `RewriteBase` does not do anything. The `RewriteBase` directive overrides the base URL-path to be used in relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule` directive. For example, given the following:

```
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar [L]
```

With the above, if you request `/foo` then the request will be internally rewritten to `/folder1/folder1/bar` because the *substitution* string `bar` is *relative*. This is the same as stating the following:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ /folder1/folder2/bar [L]
```

That is all the `RewriteBase` directive does. You don't strictly need it here, but you can use it if you want to.

> and this file is located in "/folder1/folder2/", but it does nothing ...

You need to target requests for the document root, so you can't put this `.htaccess` file in the `/folder1/folder2/` directory - it simply won't do anything. A `.htaccess` file located at `/folder1/folder2/.htaccess` will only target requests to `/folder1/folder2/` and all subdirectories thereof.

By the sounds of it you want to internally rewrite all requests from the document root to the `/folder1/folder2/` directory - effectively hiding `/folder1/folder2/` from the user.

For this you need to use something like the following in the `/.htaccess` file located in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^folder1/folder2 /folder1/folder2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The above rewrites any request that is not already for `/folder1/folder2` to that subdirectory.

> also the user need to be able to include `../../etc/passwd`

I'm not sure how you are intending to "include" this, but if you are referring to client-side URL-paths then you should not use relative URL-paths like this. Use root-relative URL-paths eg. `/etc/passwd` (from the document root).

> How to write a `.htaccess` that changes `/folder1/folder2/` to `/`

Note that this `.htaccess` file does the complete opposite. It changes URLs that request `/` (the document root) to `/folder1/folder2/` - which seems to be the requirement in your question. You need to have already changed `/folder1/folder2/` to `/` in your internal links.

Comment: Thank you a lot !
I'll try it out as soon as I can.

Also I intend to include it with a simple "include $_GET['page'];"
Hopefully this htaccess doesn't redirect includes to the subdirectory but only browser requests.

Comment: This will not redirect ordinary PHP includes (if that is what you are referring to). `.htaccess` works on HTTP requests. An ordinary PHP include is not an HTTP request.